# Averages of the same population but different samples

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

Let's assume I have a finite population $N$ and that I draw two samples from it $n_1$, and $n_2$. A single observation can belong to both samples.

Calculating the averages for each sample and the confidence intervals is simple enough. I want to know can I combine the two samples somehow to obtain a tighter confidence intervals on the average.

Based on the comments, I want to clarify. The data does not contain enough information to identify the observation. I am given the average, the variance and the number of observations for each sample.

Comment: Consider each sample as a set of individuals selected from the population. Unless one of the two samples completely contains the other, the union of the two samples will contain more individuals than either sample alone and so can be expected to give tighter confidence intervals. Does your data set include enough information to identify the union of the two samples?

Comment: I think  you mean 'a single _observation_ can belong to both samples. In the extreme, that would mean that the smaller sample is a subset of the larger one. Just from what you have said, the shortest CI will result from the larger of the samples, and you can't be sure of doing better than that.